# python; reading file path error

Tags: python, path, absolute-path, os.path, pathlib

i have a directory structure;

`DIR1:
----outerPyFile.py
----DIR2:
--------innerPyFile.py
--------DIR3:
------------fileToRead.csv`

---

I'm reading fileToRead.csv in **innerPyFile**: `pd.read_csv('DIR3/fileToRead.csv')`
*works fine if i run innerPyFile.py individually*

Now when import innerPyFile module inside outerPyFile.py as
`import innerPyFile`
-- FileNotFoundError: `DIR3\\fileToRead.csv.` does not exist

i tried replacing path with **absolute path** in innerPyFile as `pd.read_csv(os.path.abspath('DIR3/fileToRead.csv'))`

still, when i run outerPyFile i get,
FileNotFoundError `C:\\\DIR1\\\DIR3\\\fileToRead.csv` does not exist,

*here the code omitted DIR2 so i changed code as* `pd.read_csv(os.path.abspath('DIR2/DIR3/fileToRead.csv'))`

Now the code structure works file when i run outerPyFile.py which is acceptable.
but here the problem will arise when i run innerPyFile individually because it will search for DIR2 which is not there in CWD of innerPyFile.

anyone can suspect this behavior,
please revert me what is going on?

FYI, I've also tried **pathLib** module which didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**innerPyFile.py**

```
import os
script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__) # i.e. /path/to/dir/foobar.py
script_dir = os.path.split(script_path)[0] #i.e. /path/to/dir/
rel_path = "DIR3/fileToRead.csv"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

pd.read_csv(abs_file_path)
```

**outerPyFile.py**

```
import DIR2.innerPyFile
#......do something.....
```